# Exception occurs when building compile target in Liferay theme

Tags: java, ant, compilation, themes, liferay

Suddenly my Liferay theme, which was compiling ok previously, started to generate exception on Ant build.

Exception is following:

```
compile:
     [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
     [java]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
     [java]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
     [java]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:324)
     [java]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:244)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     [java]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java]     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:251)
     [java]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.ThumbnailBuilder.main(ThumbnailBuilder.java:33)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152)
     [java]     ... 51 more
     [java] Java Result: -1
```

Task, generating this exception is probably following

```
<java
    classname="com.liferay.portal.tools.ThumbnailBuilder"
    classpathref="portal.classpath">
    <arg value="thumbnail.original.file=@{file}" />
    <arg value="thumbnail.thumbnail.file=${thumbnail.file}" />
    <arg value="thumbnail.height=120" />
    <arg value="thumbnail.width=160" />
    <arg value="thumbnail.overwrite=false" />
</java>
```

What probably was changed in the project so that is starts to generate this exception?

**UPDATE**

Have added the echos

```
<sequential>
                        <propertyregex input="@{file}" override="yes" property="thumbnail.file" regexp="screenshot\.png" replace="thumbnail\.png" />

                        <echo> file @{file} </echo>
                        <echo> thumbnail.file ${thumbnail.file} </echo>

                        <java
                            classname="com.liferay.portal.tools.ThumbnailBuilder"
                            classpathref="portal.classpath"
                        >
                            <arg value="thumbnail.original.file=@{file}" />
                            <arg value="thumbnail.thumbnail.file=${thumbnail.file}" />
                            <arg value="thumbnail.height=120" />
                            <arg value="thumbnail.width=160" />
                            <arg value="thumbnail.overwrite=false" />
                        </java>
                    </sequential>
```

and found, that both files are well and existing.

Comment: My best bet is to look to the values of `@{file}` and `${thumbnail.file}` which may be empty or incorrect.

Comment: modify the `build.xml` and add `<echo> file @{file} </echo>` and `<echo> file ${thumbnail.file} </echo>` before the first `<arg`. Also alternatively check if you have not deleted the thumbnail accidentally or changed its path. Also try to check if you have changed anything regarding the thumbnail in `look-and-feel.xml`.

Comment: So, when did you start getting these exceptions? Did you update anything (e.g. the liferay-related repositories) right before you see the exceptions? Maybe a recent update in `com.liferay.portal.tools.ThumbnailBuilder` broke it (and that happens a lot).

Comment: I can't say. Probably I update nothing. I have one more theme, which is more simple, and it is compiled ok, under the same SDK folder.